# Doubts regarding handling the state of pages in Wp7 Phone App

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have the application ,in which i save the state of the page and while deactivate the application,and once i get in foreground the application,i will restore the data.But when i click the back button at the time,i don't have the Object instance for the previous page .So how can i handle at that time?

On BackKey Press,I need to some thing like

1)Check the pages in the stack,remove the previous page and create the new instance of the page or any other think?

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be saved when your application is deactivated and reloaded when your application is restored. It sounds like you are not restoring your data correctly.

This is where using something like MVVM model where your data is separate from your UI code is really helpful. Check out the MVVM light toolkit on CodePlex.

http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

It is too general a question to give more specific answers than that. Sorry.

Try coding up something and posting specific questions regarding your code.

Comment: Hi AndrewJ,I can save the data for page that has been deactivated,But i dont save the page state for previous pages.on backkey pres of the saved Page,Can i load the data for the previous page by makking HTTP connection and to load data using the PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded method.if that case,how to get the instance of PhoneApplicationPages which are in stack?

Comment: what is your intention? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Rakesh, the data for your app really should be independant of the UI. As I said before, look at the MVVM model for separating data from the UI code. This will help you by being able to save the data model independantly of what page you are on.